# What is directory "//"?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

On various linux machines you can

```
cd /
```

and

```
cd //
```

The shell will say the current directory is '/' or '//' after using the corresponding command.

So the question is: What is the difference between '/' and '//', and if the answer is 'no difference' then why is '//' shown differently than '/'

BTW

```
cd ///
cd ////
cd /////
```

All result in the shell saying the current directory is '/'

Heres an example session:

```
[user@host /]$ cd //
[user@host //]$ cd /
[user@host /]$ cd //
[user@host //]$ cd /
[user@host /]$
```

Comment: This appears to be a bash-specific anomaly. If you try `cd //` in csh or zsh and then `pwd` it will show just '/'

Comment: interesting -  that sheds some light on it

Comment: For comparison: `cd //usr/bin` gives "//usr/bin", but `cd /usr//bin` gives "/usr/bin" (in Bash).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's ask [the man himself](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) (Chester Ramey):

> E10) Why does 'cd //' leave $PWD as
>   '//'?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of 'cd',
>   says that *three* or more leading
>   slashes may be replaced with a single
>   slash when canonicalizing the current
>   working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical
>   compatibility.  Certain versions of
>   Unix, and early network file systems,
>   used paths of the form //hostname/path
>   to access 'path' on server 'hostname'.

Comment: Much better answer than the (already pretty good) one from John T.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't an actual directory, it's a problem specific with bash. It's referenced in [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#CDREF).

Comment: why hasn't anyone fixed it? or have they?